# ASP.NET Panels & Dynamic Controls

Tags: asp.net, textbox, panel, justify

I have a simple form, with a table (from the standard toolbox - 3 X 4). In one of the cells I have a panel, which I add textboxes to dynamically at runtime.

Problem is this: How can I have the panel LEFT-justified in the cell, yet have my textboxes RIGHT-justified within the panel? (and, possibly the text right-justified inside the textboxes)

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the panels's [HorizontalAlign](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.horizontalalign.aspx) property to `HorizontalAlign.Right`

As for the TextBox, you can do

```
dynamicTextBox.Style.Add("text-align", "right");
```